# When i Try to connect to firebase it loading only but not connected?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

i try to much but it is not connected

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8otDo.png]

Comment: The problem might be with the URL

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you you have done the following:

1. [Downloaded](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) the latest *GoogleService-Info.plist* and include it in your project. You need to do this every time you [carry out certain changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946176/when-i-try-to-connect-to-firebase-it-loading-only-but-not-connected#comment94751219_53946527) on your Firebase App. **Make sure your App BundleID in Firebase App matches your App BundleID in Xcode**.
2. Imported the Firebase module in your `UIApplicationDelegate`:

`import Firebase`

3. Configured a FirebaseApp shared instance, typically in your application's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

`FirebaseApp.configure()`

Source: [Firebase iOS setup docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

If you have more than one App BundleID then you need multiple *GoogleService-Info.plist* files, one file for each App BundleID. In that case see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

---

You are getting downvoted by other people for the following reasons:

1. You haven't provided your previous work, what steps did you take? So we can tell what you're missing.
2. You haven't stated if you read and tried the steps mentioned in Firebase docs (you have to source them too).
3. You haven't stated if you actually looked this solution up. If you did you should end up in Firebase docs.

It's a good thing you used the correct tags though.

Comment: Hold up.... *Downloaded the latest GoogleService-Info.plist and include it in your project. You need to do this every time you carry out changes on your Firebase App* is not accurate at all. Please do not do that as it's unnecessary. You only ever need to do it once, when you first create your app. After that, its static data. The rest of the answer is spot on.

Comment: @Jay There may actually be cases where not all keys are present straight away. So the documentation may be over-eager, but it's not incorrect.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. Hmm. what keys are we referring to? I think the answer is implying that if you make a change to your project, like add a *print('Hello, World')* line to your code then you should re-download the plist. Every time, for every change. Where do keys come into play?

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean. You indeed only need to do this when you make changes to your Firebase project (typically in the console).

Comment: @Jay what you said is true. I only meant changes to the Firebase App. The *GoogleService-Info.plist* contains the following: **This file contains configuration details such as keys and identifiers, for the services you just enabled**. One might carry out changes to relevant Firebase services enabling/modifying them or their keys for this particular Firebase App, or any other properties inside the plist. Those changes require re-downloading the latest plist file from the App's console, for them, the changes, to be effective in the iOS app that corresponds to the Firebase App via the BundleID.

Comment: Nice update, and a good answer. Upvoted you. Thanks for the clarification! I wish the OP would clarify their question too.